# Using typeof to convert a variable declaration to a type?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, typeof

Currently, I have a scenario much like this:

```
#define my_macro(var) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(var), foo) ? do_something : do_something_else
```

However, inadvertently the macro gets passed this parameter:

```
my_macro(int x);
```

Which of course fails, because `typeof(int x)` isn't valid.

Is there a transformation I can apply inside the `my_macro` which will allow `typeof` to work on that expression? I cannot change what is passed into the macro, only what happens inside the macro.

So, something like this:

```
#define my_macro(var) typeof(?? var ??)
```

Or, is there another expression I should be using here?

Comment: I'm going to say "no", although obviously a negative is somewhat difficult to prove ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was fearing that... I know that I could probably do it with `decltype`, but I really want to avoid C++ here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way to do it, using yet another GCC extension, this time the statement expression:

```
#define my_typeof(definition) typeof(({ definition, _def; _def; }))
```

Which, of course, expands to:

```
typeof(({ int x, _def; _def; }))
```

Pretty ugly, but why do I care? It works.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth good catch. It'd be interesting to see if there exists a solution that would work for pointers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle `x` or `int x` separately but to handle both with one macro you would need the ability to parse/separate a space-delimited argument within the C preprocessor. To my knowledge, no such support exists in the C preprocessor. Without such parsing capabilities you must find some other clever way to write a macro that works around this limitation, for example, something in the spirit of `my_macro2()` in the following code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define my_macro1(var) \
do { \
   typeof(var) blah; \
   printf("sizeof(var)=%d\n", sizeof(blah)); \
} while(0)

#define my_macro2(var) \
do { \
   var, newvar_sametype; \
   typeof(newvar_sametype) blah; \
   printf("sizeof(newvar_sametype)=%d\n", sizeof(blah)); \
} while(0)


int
main()
{
   int x;
   my_macro1(x);
   my_macro2(char y);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty neat, but note that `my_macro2` won't work correctly for pointer types.